# Prove subgaussian norm of sugaurssian random variables is a norm

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

I know how to prove the zero and scaling property of norm. However I'm stuck on proving triangle inequality. The definition of norm of sub-Gaussian random variable is. Sub-Gaussian random variable is such norm exists.

$$\|X\|_{\psi_2}=\inf\{t>0:E e^{-\frac{X^2}{t^2}}\}$$

Answer (score 22):

I think you mistake the definition.

**sub-Gaussian norm** is

$$
   \|X\|_{\psi_2} = \inf\left\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp\left( X^2/t^2\right)\le2\right\}.
$$

What you want to show that is

$$
   \|X+Y\|_{\psi_2} \le  \|X\|_{\psi_2} +  \|Y\|_{\psi_2}.
$$

To show this, Let $f(x) = e^{x^2} $ which is increasing and convex.

Then, we have

$$
  f\left(\frac{|X+Y|}{a+b} \right) \le f\left(\frac{|X|+|Y|}{a+b} \right)\\
\le \frac{a}{a+b}f\left(\frac{|X|}{a}\right) + \frac{b}{a+b}f\left(\frac{|Y|}{b}\right)
$$
by Jensen's Inequality. After that, taking expectations,
$$
  \mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{|X+Y|}{a+b} \right) 
\le \frac{a}{a+b}\mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{|X|}{a}\right) + \frac{b}{a+b}\mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{|Y|}{b}\right).
$$

If we insert $a=\|X\|_{\psi_2}, b=\|Y\|_{\psi_2}$, then by definition, we have

$$
   \mathbb{E}f\left(\frac{|X+Y|}{\|X\|_{\psi_2}+\|Y\|_{\psi_2}} \right) \le
\frac{a}{a+b}\times2 + \frac{b}{a+b}\times2 = 2.
$$

So, $\|X\|_{\psi_2}+\|Y\|_{\psi_2}$ is in the set $\left\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp\left( (X+Y)^2/t^2\right)\le2\right\}$, and it completes the proof as follows:

$$
   \|X + Y\|_{\psi_2} \le \|X\|_{\psi_2}+\|Y\|_{\psi_2}.
$$

Comment: I don't quite see how the last step works. I understand that $\|X\| + \|Y\|$ is in the desired set, but why does this immediately imply the claim?